# TwitterKit for Swift not displaying Images

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, swift2

**Issue**

When loading returned Twitter JSON feed into the TwitterKit Table View Cell, the Profile Image and Media Image does not load.  All other data (user name, Retweet status, description, links) loads and is shown correctly in the twitterTableView, but the images do not.

The JSON feed contains accurate image URL's.

Has anyone experienced this, or have a solution that allows for a nested Twitter table inside a View Controller?

**Version Info**

Xcode v7.0.1

Code Base: Swift 2.0

App Compatibility iOS 8.3+

TwitterCore v1.12.0

TwitterKit v1.12.0

**ViewController in Storyboard**

- View
- - ScrollView
- - - InfoView (for other info)
- - - SocialView (for info on the Twitter Profile, and Twitter Feed)
- - - - ProfileInfoView
- - - - twitterTable (no assigned class, with ViewController as datasource & delegate)
- - - - - twitterTableViewCell (assigned TWTRTweetTableViewCell class)

**Metadata Workflow**

1. App calls Proprietary Server API
2. Server either:

   - Return cached Twitter JSON
   - Call Twitter API with search term.  Cache Twitter JSON response.  Return Twitter JSON.
3. App parses JSON, and utilizes TWTRTweet.tweetsWithJSONArray to set var *tweets*
4. On *tweets* set, update *twitterTable* with *tweets*

**Relevant Code in the ViewController**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import RealmSwift
import TwitterKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, TWTRTweetViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var socialView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var friendCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var twitterTableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var friendColletionViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var twitterTableViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!


    var tweets: [TWTRTweet] = [] {
        didSet {
            twitterTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    var tweetHeights:[Int:CGFloat] = [:]

    var isLoadingTweets = false
    let tweetTableCellReuseIdentifier = "TweetCell"
    var prototypeCell: TWTRTweetTableViewCell?

    var isLoadingFriend = false
    var friends:[Friend] = [] {
        didSet {
            friendCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        

        self.loadInfo()
        self.loadFriends()
        self.loadTweets()

        // Create a single prototype cell for height calculations.
        self.prototypeCell = TWTRTweetTableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: tweetTableCellReuseIdentifier)

        // Register the identifier for TWTRTweetTableViewCell.
        self.twitterTableView.registerClass(TWTRTweetTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: tweetTableCellReuseIdentifier)
    }

    func loadInfo(){
        print("loads basic info")
        // code removed to simplify post
    }

    func loadFriends(){
        print("loads friendsCollectionView inside Info")
        // code removed to simplify post
    }

    func loadTweets(){
        print("loadTweets")
        // Do not trigger another request if one is already in progress.
        if self.isLoadingTweets {
            return
        }
        self.isLoadingTweets = true

        Alamofire.request(APIService.Router.TwitterSearch(searchType: "hashtag", searchTerm: "something", userSocialProfileID: ""))
            .responseString { response in
                print("request: \(response.0!)")
                print("\n*******loadTweets********\n\n\(response.2.value!)\n\n**************\n")
            }
            .responseJSON { response in
                // print("\n*******loadTweets:JSON********\n\n\(response.2.value!)\n\n**************\n")

                if let json = response.2.value {
                    var jsonObj = JSON(json)

                    if let results = jsonObj["results"].dictionary{
                        if let jsonTweets = results["statuses"]!.arrayObject {
                            // print("The tweets are \n\(jsonTweets)")
                            self.tweets = TWTRTweet.tweetsWithJSONArray(jsonTweets) as! [TWTRTweet]
                        } else {
                            print("jsonTweets are not an array of Objects")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Results is not a dictionary.")
                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                        self.twitterTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
                        for (_, tweetHeight) in self.tweetHeights {
                            self.twitterTableViewHeightConstraint.constant += tweetHeight
                        }
                        self.isLoadingTweets = false
                    })

                } else {
                    print("value was not json...or something is wrong with the code")
                }
        }

    }

    //MARK: UITABLEVIEW
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tweets.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let tweet = self.tweets[indexPath.row] as TWTRTweet!
        if tweets.count > indexPath.row {
            prototypeCell?.configureWithTweet(tweet)
        }

        let tweetHeight = TWTRTweetTableViewCell.heightForTweet(tweet, width: tableView.bounds.width)

        self.tweetHeights[indexPath.row] = tweetHeight
        return tweetHeight
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(tweetTableCellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TWTRTweetTableViewCell

        // Assign the delegate to control events on Tweets.
        cell.tweetView.delegate = self

        cell.tweetView.showActionButtons = false
        cell.tweetView.linkTextColor = UIColor().cosMediumPurple()

        // Retrieve the Tweet model from loaded Tweets.
        let tweet = tweets[indexPath.row] as TWTRTweet!

        // Configure the cell with the Tweet.
        cell.configureWithTweet(tweet)

        // Return the Tweet cell.
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent bug report.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually very annoying and simple. The class TWTRTweet does not contain variables for profile images or attached media. Twitter provides the method:

```
TWTRTweet.tweetsWithJSONArray()
```

But that method immediately discards any URL for images that you need. You'll need to build a custom parsing method. I've done some work with Twitter JSON parsing you can check out [here.](https://github.com/wagnercasey/BirdFeed)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is likely caused by mismatched SHA1 certificates on iOS 9 being impacted by Apple's new **App Transport Security**. You can work around the issue by providing an ATS exception for `pbs.twimg.com` to your `Info.plist` file (http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/).

You can diagnose the issue more closely by loading an image using the `nscurl` command with the `--ats-diagnostics` option:

```
nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2044921128/finals.png
```

Since only some of the CDN servers have these old SHA1 certs you won't always see the issue. And since Twitter Kit is handling image caching for you, it might not be obvious when an image load would have failed since it hit a properly configured server at some point in the past.

Here's an example of the issue occurring in the simulator:

[image]